# Android library upgrade, toolbar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-appcompat

Hi I need to change actionbar to toolbar in mi application and i have this issue.

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.

And i cant find this library, any clues are welcome, thanks in advice!.

Comment: See here http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support version of `Toolbar` is in the v7 support library.

Adding the support library is described at the [Support Library Setup](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) page of the Android documentation. Be sure that you are adding v7. You may already have v4- if so, then do not remove it. v7 is *not* an update to v4, but rather a separate library with different features.